# Decrypt file without extension

Tags: encryption

I had given an assignment to decrypt a file called Q3_encrypted and a AES secret key for the file. However,there is no extension for this file so how can i determine the file type of this file. The lecturer ask us to figure out ourselves but i have no idea how to start? Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with what the lecturer taught during the lectures. Any information about this would help.

Comment: Can't you put the file extension inside the file encrypted in the first or last n bytes, so you decrypt that part first?

Comment: So far, the lecturer had taught us RSA and AES and i got a AES secret key for the file from the lecturer.So i think it might be related to AES.

Comment: @demonofnight you mean simply put an extension for the file like Q3_encrypted.txt? i had try this but it come out a lot of unknown code.

Comment: Sounds like it is binary then. Take the first 16 bytes and show it here in hexadecimals. Then perform a block decrypt over the first 16 bytes. If it is legible you have either ECB encryption or CBC encryption with an IV of all zero values. If it is not legible, you can try to use the first 16 bytes as IV for CBC mode decryption.

Comment: @owlstead u mean open that file in MS word and copy the unknown code here? Our lecturer ask us to decrypt it using ECB

Comment: you can take a look at the file command in linux ( the source code ) the file identify the probram bu the signature and not by the extension

Comment: Binary files are best viewed by a hex editor. If you haven't got one, I would urge you to download an open source one. What platform are you on, and what programming language are you going to use?

Comment: @owlstead i am using window and i am going to use java

Answer (score 1):

Applications generally look for a [special signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) when loading a specific file type.  If the entire file is encrypted, however, the signature will not be present.  Instead, look for signs of common encryption techniques such as the trailing "=" often found in Base64-encrypted strings.

Edit:
If you already have a key and know it's AES, have you tried using it as the decode key?

Comment: erm..sorry, i don't really understand because i am new in this. Can u explain further?